# Shortest Path from Node A to B by going through all other Nodes (NP-Hard?)

Tags: graph, shortest-path, np, np-hard, hamiltonian-cycle

My problem: Find the shortest path from node `A` to node `B` that passes through all other nodes of the unweighted, direct graph. I know that there exists such a path.

I believe this is NP-Hard, but I can't explain it. My Prof. likes to have the algorithm perform on a runtime of `O(|V| + |E|)`, where `V` is the set of nodes and `E` the set of edges.

It seems it is similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664503/find-the-shortest-path-in-a-graph-visiting-all-nodes#_=_), but the Graph's properties are different, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's NP-hard.  If your solver ran in P, then by running it on every pair of points you'd have a P-time solver for [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).

The [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36665121/238419) gives a more rigorous proof.